# load same image without cache into hidden div

Tags: javascript, image, html

Hi I am trying to load the image into a hidden div. I need to do this many times and I don't want to load image from cache. Here is the code.

```
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = '<img src="http://blog.dwolla.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png" onload="onLoad()" />'

function onLoad() {
    alert()
}
```

Is there a way to do that without cache?
Thank you...

Comment: Can you not ask the server side to send a no-cache header?

Comment: how about adding timestamp to image url?

Comment: I can't ask the server side for header :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append some random parameter to image `src` so cache will not be used:

```
var img = '<img src="http://blog.dwolla.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png?' + Math.random() + '" onload="onLoad()" />';
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = img;
```

Comment: random can be duplicated time by time, but timestamp never

Comment: While possible this seems very unlikely that it is duplicated (0.011268550995737314), unless you make like ten billions tries. But you are right, better to use timestamp: `"<img src='image.jpg?" + +new Date + "'> "`;

Comment: Actually I am trying to measure download speed with this method. before for same picture I was having 22 mbit/s which is my real speed and later it was loading from cache. now it doesn't load from cache but it everytime shows 0.58 mbit/s do you have any idea why it happened??

Comment: Hm, no idea. However I guess there are another reliable methods to find out your download speed. Try to compare.

Comment: yes actually i am using another methods but I have difficulties with browser support. so now trying the simplest one. I hope I will figure out. Thank you for answer..

Answer (score 3):

```
var img = '<img src="http://blog.dwolla.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png?' + Number(new Date()) + '" onload="onLoad()" />';
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = img;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a random string on to the end of the img url

like:

```
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = '<img src="http://blog.dwolla.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png?nocache='+Math.random()+'" onload="onLoad()" />'
```